# Checkpointing in high availability

Tags: hadoop, high-availability

In Hadoop high availability, Check pointing is done by which node?
Is there a secondary name node in addition to the active and the stand-by nodes which does the check pointing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Standby NameNode maintains enough state to be a quick failover

> [I]n an HA cluster, the Standby NameNode also performs checkpoints of the namespace state, and thus it is not necessary to run a Secondary NameNode, CheckpointNode, or BackupNode in an HA cluster. In fact, to do so would be an error

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithNFS.html#Architecture

> *Is there a secondary name node in addition to the active and the stand-by nodes*

There is only one active and one standby, as mentioned also on that page.

> Currently, only a maximum of two NameNodes may be configured per nameservice